# JasperReports generates a report with ruined HTML markup

Tags: jasper-reports

I have created a report which, when generated in *pdf* or *docx* format, looks the way I want it to. However, when I generate the report in *HTML* format, the resulting document is ruined. Embedded images are missing, field formatting for tables differs from the one in pdf or docx, a separate block for page background is generated, a lot of `<img alt="" src="nullpx"/>` tags are generated:

```
<tr valign="top">
  <td><img alt="" src="nullpx" style="width: 20px; height: 19px;"/></td>
  <td colspan="4"><p style="overflow: hidden; line-height: 1.0; text-indent: 0px; "><span style="font-family: 'Times New Roman', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;">Common information</span></p></td>
  <td colspan="5"><img alt="" src="nullpx" style="width: 168px; height: 19px;"/></td>
  <td colspan="2"><img alt="" src="nullpx" style="width: 20px; height: 19px;"/></td>
</tr>
```

This is how the HTML version looks:
[image]

and this is the docx version:
[image]

Any ideas why this may be happening?

Comment: Try stretching the text box that reads "Common Information" all the way across the columns below it -- make it the same width as the Name Surname text box. It looks like the template is attempting to fill in the empty space after "Common Information".

Comment: @Lisa, it also tries to do the same with empty space before each table row. The question is why it does that and how to avoid it. Missing images are also an issue.

Comment: The missing images might be due to overlapping elements: http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/522891/no-formatting-html-export